# Is there a way to Get username & id of current user in Remote Bff Api Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microservices, .net-6.0, duende-identity-server

Can someone guide me or put me in the right direction? I'm new with microservices and Identityserver. I googled it but it's mostly about doing in mvc app that's not my scenario.

I have 3 projects in my .sln file

FrontendHost //Bff frontend dotnet react app

IdentityService //Asp.net mvc app Duende IdentityServer 6 for protecting Apis. Added claims here are openid, profile, email

BackendApi1 //.net6 web api that is protected using Remote Bff Api Endpoint approach.

I've a string Created By field in a model inside BackendApi1 project and in its api controller I wanna assign it with current signed-in user's name.

I tried with

```
var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

But didn't get the expected result.

Comment: "didn't get the expected result"  Please explain what result you did get. In your question. Does the user have a claim to their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a front-end with a BFF can be pretty daunting. It's complicated to grasp the concepts. That's why I've built a simple open source BFF implementation free for anyone to use.

First, it is important to understand how API authorization works. I have tried to describe it best i can in this article: https://bff.gocloudnative.org/concepts/api-authorization/

Once you understand how API authorization works, it is important to understand that a BFF works as a reverse proxy. It delegates requests "downstream" as it were, i've tried to describe what a reverse proxy does here: https://bff.gocloudnative.org/concepts/what-is-a-reverse-proxy/

In your case, when you create an asp.net core project with a react app in it, there is a server-side component which is both the BFF and the host for the SPA. This can be quite confusing. That's why I would recommend creating one front-end project and a seperate BFF. Then you'd get the following infrastructure: https://bff.gocloudnative.org/concepts/bff-security-pattern/

I understand that still, this is pretty much to grasp and apply, that's why i've created three sample apps. The spa is built in Angular, but you can replace it with a React spa if you like:

- [A bff + aspnetcore api + angular spa + auth0](https://github.com/thecloudnativewebapp/GoCloudNative.Bff/tree/main/docs/demos/Auth0/src)
- [A bff + aspnetcore api + angular spa + identityserver4](https://github.com/thecloudnativewebapp/GoCloudNative.Bff/tree/main/docs/demos/IdentityServer4/src)
- [A bff + aspnetcore api + angular spa + azure ad](https://github.com/thecloudnativewebapp/GoCloudNative.Bff/tree/main/docs/demos/AzureAd/src)

In these samples you can see how you must configure your API in order to het `context.Identity...` to work properly.

Please refer to these articles to see how you must configure the identity provider and the BFF for everything to work properly:

- https://bff.gocloudnative.org/integration-manuals/quickstarts/auth0/quickstart/
- https://bff.gocloudnative.org/integration-manuals/quickstarts/azuread/quickstart/
- https://bff.gocloudnative.org/integration-manuals/quickstarts/identityserver4/quickstart/

Today and tomorrow I'll be working on some bicep templates which demonstrate how to deploy this in Azure Container Apps. Next week i'll write about how to deploy this in Kubernetes.

Hope this helps!!